# Distinquish between jpa DataIntegration exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, exception

I have an entity

```
@Entity
class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String name;
}
```

Now when name is null, or its length is greater than 10, the `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown by JPA.

Is there a way how to distinquish it?

I have ADviceController

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlers {
    @ExceptionHandler(value =  DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorsMessage> handleViolation(DataIntegrityViolationException e ){
      return new ResponseEntity(ErrorMessage(value),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }
}
```

What i want to do, is set `value` of ErrorMessage object that is returned to "null parameter" when name is being null , and if the name is greater than 10 set the value to `long parameter`

Is there a way how to distinquish it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Not quite sure, but you could try to go via the `message` or the `cause`. Both do hold a bit information, but I don't know what information exactly and if it does differ.

Comment: That is not a JPA exception, and instead a SPRING exception.

Answer (score 0):

The information about the constraint violation is included in the exception itself and could be extracted with getting the [most specific casue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException.html#getMostSpecificCause--) and its message:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value =  DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorsMessage> handleViolation(DataIntegrityViolationException e ){
    String message = e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();
    // ...
}
```

Edit: In the method's body, you can perform an operation over the extracted message and return the response or rethrow your custom exception.

Comment: yes, but thats the error message thrown by JPA, i want to return custom message, i would not like to create if statemenet hell for this , + what if i wanted to add collumn that violated integrity + custom message?

Comment: @Johnyb if you have distinguised the errors, then you can throw your own exception with the custom message

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes but i would have to do smth like if(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage().match("null"){...} or wouldnt i?

Comment: @Johnyb exactly. There is no way around it as they use the same exception class for both cases

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Agreed and thanks - I've edited the answer.